# exclude a jar from dependancy in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, viewpagerindicator

I have following dependancy in my gradle

```
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
        compile('com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1')
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
```

Where `com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1` includes `android-support-v4` but my project uses v13. Is there any way from gradle I can tell the module `viewpagerindicator:library` to use v13 ?

As of now I am getting `Error:(193, 23) error: cannot find symbol method postInvalidateOnAnimation(BezelImageView)` due to `viewpagerindicator:library` overwriting v13 functonalities

Answer (score 1):

The "v4" and "v13" in the support library name does not reference specific versions of the support library- they refer to the minimum SDK that specific support library supports. You cannot simply replace v4 with v13 because the v4 library contains APIs that the v13 library does not have.

Currently there are 4 different Android support libraries- v4, v7, v8, and v13. You should think of each as a unique library. You can use one all of them at the same time if you really want to. The classes in each library are in a `android.support.vX` package where X is the version of the support library that you are using. Thus classes from the v4 support library will not "overwrite" classes in the v13 library.

Secondly, the method that you are looking for ([`postInvalidateOnAnimation(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#postInvalidateOnAnimation(android.view.View))) does not exist in the v13 support library. It belongs to the v4 support library.

Finally, dependencies for libraries are not typically exported. That is, if the ViewPagerIndicator library uses the v4 support library and you want to use the v4 support library, you still need to add the v4 support library to your dependencies to access those classes.

Long story short, all you should really need to do at this point to get your application to compile is add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v14:19.1.0'` to your dependencies.